# Remove a hyperlink with YUI

Tags: yui

I have the following in my html:

```
Logged in as <a title="View Profile" href="http://xxx/user/profile.php?">Peter Pan</a>
```

I would like to just remove the hyperlink form the above, so that is still displays "Logged in as Peter Pan" but just without Peter Pan linking to anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming YUI 3: `node.set('innerHTML', node.get('innerHTML').replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ''));`

Note that this doesn't require YUI as much as plain regexp :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Node.removeAttribute` method to remove the anchor's `href`.

Take a look at its documentation in the [YUI API](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/):

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_removeAttribute

```
Y.one('some selector for the anchor here').removeAttribute('href');
```